# Test Application Guide for Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, testing, forms

I'm a C# developer in a medium/small company. I do quick tests of the apps that my workmates made and they test my applications. We test each form based on our experience. (Yes, I know this is not a very formal method.)

Now a new guy without experience is going to join our team. We think now is the moment to make a little list of things that we all should test in each form. Divided by categories. For example:

- Usability: Test that the tab order of each control is properly set; or
- Validation: Test that the max length of each textbox matches with the max length of a field in the DB...

etc.

We don't want to reinvent the wheels, so I want to know if such kind of document already exists.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know exactly what you're looking for, because some time ago I worked in a small company that tested its products exactly in the way you describe. Since then, I've learned a wee bit more about testing.

I can't recommend any particular "testing checklist", but would like to give one very general piece of advice:

**Before you sit down to write such a document, make sure that it will only contain tests that you cannot automate.**

There are things that you cannot test automatically; such as the tab order of controls in a form. This is because tab order only makes sense to a human user; a computer couldn't care less how your controls are arranged visually, and whether your tab order proceeds from the first control to the last, and then back to the second, and finally over to the opposite end of the form. These are things that should be tested by humans (IMO). (Even humans won't always agree on the "right" tab order, but that's another issue.)

Then there are tests that can be done automatically. Matching the maximum length of an input field against the capacity of a DB field is potentially one such test and IMO you should strive towards a solution where such a test won't have to be done by humans. Sometimes you'll find a framework that automatically checks such things for you; sometimes you might want to write unit tests; sometimes all that's needed is validating a form's input data before it gets written to the DB; etc. There's many solutions in this area.

Answer (score 1):

The items you list are not tests in the traditional sense.  You'd need some kind of static analysis tool, similar to FxCop or StyleCop.  I'm not aware of a product made specifically for Windows Forms that can do what you listed.  That usually requires massively parallel computing hardware, the kind that the new guy carries between his ears.

Don't hesitate to run FxCop btw, you'll probably get plenty of flags if you've never subjected your code to it before.  StyleCop is good if the new guy complains about coding standards.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use the Design/Requirement document that describs how your application should work and use that as a template for the testing